# How to update the path of PHP to the new version I just installed on mac osx mountain lion?

Tags: php, macos

first I am new to macs, I just installed PHP 5.4.6 on my machine after downloading the PHP package from http://www.php.net, I unzipped it and navigated to the directory through the terminal, then I ran the following commands:

```
./configure --with-config-file-path=~/php-5.4.6/php.ini
make
make test
sudo make install
```

I restarted the Apache with `sudo apachectl graceful` but and when I gone to the info.php it still said PHP 5.3.13 the default version that macs shipped with, I tried to run `echo $PATH` I got this result `/usr/local/php5:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin` when I searched the internet they said something about changing the path because the default PHP is installed on `/usr/local/php5` and the new one is installed on `/usr/local/bin/`, when I run `/usr/local/bin/php -v` I get

```
PHP 5.4.6 (cli) (built: Aug 18 2012 22:52:55) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies
```

So I wanted to know how to update that path.

Thanks in advance and sorry for being long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to point your httpd.conf configuration to use your new mod_php library... assuming that you passed the proper *--with-apxs2* flag during the build.

If using the built-in Apache server, see: /etc/apache2/httpd.conf

```
LoadModule php5_module <MY_NEW_PATH>/libphp5.so
```

Comment: Do you mean add this? LoadModule php5_module /usr/local/bin/libphp5.so
I am really sorry to bother you know new guy here :S

Comment: If there isn't already an entry for it, then yes. There should be a similar line commented out on a default installation. If you don't *need* a custom PHP install, you can simply uncomment it and use the built-in install (5.3.13 on Mountain Lion).

Comment: I tried to add both this which was in the php.net documentation LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp5.so and the other one LoadModule php5_module /usr/local/bin/libphp5.so they both made apache stop working or actually redirecting to www.localhost.com

Comment: You will need to build the module. If you run 'php -i' and look for "Configure Command", you'll see that you need to add the "--with-apxs2=/usr/sbin/apxs" parameter. I'd recommend trying the built-in PHP module first.

Comment: @Pestilence where is the flag passed? Is it during ./configure?